# Set a Sharepoint file as new version of another sharepoint file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

How do i set a file existing in a library as a new version of another file in an event receiver?

E.g : i have two files in my SP library named "File.doc" and "File.pdf". I want the File.pdf to become the new version of the.doc one. and so, in my view i can only see the File.pdf, but no more File.doc. The File.doc will be in the list of old versions of File.pdf

Comment: Have you tried copying the file via REST (overwrite) and then delete the former file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this will not work as you hope. As you correctly said you have two files and for SharePoint they are two.

If you transform the .doc into a .pdf and try to save it, it would automatically become a new file.

One way to achieve what you want is to add a column to mark the .doc as "old" and a lookup column to link the .doc to the .pdf.
Then get some fancy Views and your good.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just create a view set to show all File names that contain .pdf and another for .doc, then you can swap between the 2 if needed.